# What should I use mysql_real_escape_string or addslashes vs PDO::quote?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, special-characters

I needed to insert `~!@#$%^*()_+}|:"<>?/.,'\][=-`  into mysql through PHP and also call it back. I use PDO. Will `pdo::quote` do the job? I mean all it does it convert `Co'mpl''ex "st'"ring` to quoted string: `'Co''mpl''''ex "st''"ring'`

But the function says it escapes special character. I thought to escape a special character, `\` is required in front of the special character.

Or shall I use `mysql_real_escape_string` or `addslashes` and `strip_tags`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection. If you are preparing your statement and not dynamically constructing a query then PDO already takes care of that.